# Некорректно работает javascript в Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

Есть Meteor приложение.

В нём вот такой [код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grvZLZ):

**html:**

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="div1"></div>
</header>

<div id="div2"></div>

<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

**css:**

```
header {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}
#div1 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
#div2 {
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 0;
  right: .5%;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

**js:**

```
document.getElementById('header').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.bottom = -110 + 'px';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.height = 100 + 'px';
}

document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.bottom = 0 + 'px';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.height = 0;
}
```

**Идея:**

при нажатии на Хедер у первого дива опускается координата, а у другого дива появляется высота. В итоге имеем аналог выдвижной панели (все элементарно). НО: в Метеоре данный код выполняется не параллельно, а как-то жутко криво: первый див падает быстрее, чем растет высота у второго. При том что `transition` указана одинаковая продолжительность. Пробовал через `&.animate` - тоже самое, криво все двигается, блоки анимируются независимо друг от друга.

Как быть? нужна обычная выдвижная панель, но ни в какую не работает...

Братцы! Всю ночь потратил на решение этого вопроса, но так и не продвинулся ни на каплю. Еду на работу не спавши. Узнать решение будет лучшим событием за сегодня!

Comment: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDiqh8iBOO

для наглядности захватил видео с экрана. только так работает, что я уже ни пытался сделать.

Comment: У меня в Хроме 51 на Ubuntu пен работает как надо, ничего не глючит. Скорее всего, у вас что-то параллельно тяжёлое выполняется, что фризит интерфейс.

Comment: @АлексейУколов так в том то и дело! пен работает как надо и у меня. а вот этот же самый код в метеоре работает криво (как на видео). и в чем дело - не могу разобраться, это уже принципиально.

Comment: То есть, вы ожидаете, что для решения вашей проблемы достаточно _описания_ неправильно работающего кода? При том, что выжимка из этого кода, которую вы всё-таки привели в вопросе, работает как надо?

Comment: @АлексейУколов дело в том, что для решения моей проблем я привел весь имеющийся код. смотрите: есть простейший html код (3 блока), стили к ним и обработчик щелчка мыши на js. Этот код работает корректно, если собрать все три файла (или вот я на пен выложил). НО: тот же самый код, исполняемый внутри meteor-приложения работает некорректно, а именно анимация выполняется непараллельно. Отсюда единственный возможный вывод - ту же самую вещь внутри Метеора нужно реализовать/обернуть как-то иначе. Я прошу помощи сообщества, ибо сам испробовал все варианты. Собака зарыта в метеоре, это все что я понял

Comment: Пример на codepen не работает как надо.
В этом можно убедиться если `transition` поставить `5s` вместо `.5s`. 
`div1` будет перемещаться синхронно росту высоты `div2` только в случае, когда длина пути перемещения `div1` равна высоте `div2` в крайней точке.
Например, если высота `div2` будет `100px`, чтобы обеспечить синхронность `div1` должен пройти ровно `100px`, скажем, с `bottom: -15px` до `bottom: -115px`